# How can I solve a generic error for Compare?

Tags: java, comparable

```
public class SortedLL<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SortedListInterface<T>  {

   public void add(T data) {

        int i;
        for(i=0; i<size;i++){ 
            if(data < getAt(i))                         
                break;       
        }                    
   }
}
```

[image]

I'm here to ask you a question because I don't understand this error.

The data type is generic T and the value obtained by `getAt(i)` is also `T`.

And when defining the`SortedLL` class, I declared it `<T extents Comparable <T>>`.

Does anyone know why there is an error when comparing these two values and if there is a solution?

Comment: Unless something changed when I wasn't looking, you need to call `.compareTo` instead of using comparison operators as Java doesn't support operator overloading.

Answer (score 3):

THere is no operator overloading in Java. The `<` operator is only implemented for numeric primitives, not for objects.

Using the `Comparable` interface, you can call the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method to get that behavior:

```
if (data.compareTo(getAt(i)) < 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I solve problem becase of you.